# What does this (apply swap! my-atom ...) invocation do? Why is apply necessary here?

Tags: clojure

What is the logic behind passing `swap!` as an argument to `apply` here?

```
(defonce app-state
  (r/atom
    {:contacts
     [{:first "Ben" :last "Bitdiddle" :email "benb@mit.edu"}]}))

(defn update-contacts! [f & args]
  (apply swap! app-state update-in [:contacts] f args))

(defn add-contact! [c]
  (update-contacts! conj c))
```

`apply` "gets the value inside" and can be used to turn a 'seqable data structure' into a series of arguments. Can anyone help me to *reason through* the use of `apply` here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The usual lisp lingo is that `+`, `1`, `2` and `3` are values and

```
(+ 1 2 3)
```

is an application. The parentheses means `+` is applied. In an evaluator the expression above becomes `(apply + '(1 2 3))`

`apply` is a primitive that works the same way with all functions.

```
(apply swap! app-state update-in [:contacts] f args)
```

with args being a vector or list, perhaps '(elements of args), Is the same as the normal function call:

```
(swap! app-state update-in [:contacts] f elements of args)
```

Comment: In the function `addContact` c is presumably not a vector. Does the `&` somehow change it into being a vector? If it does not, then is `apply` redundant for `addContact`?

Comment: The `& name` in the end of the argument list does the opposite of `apply`. Excess arguments are bound as a list with the name supplied. `(defn add [& args] (apply + args)) ` takes any number of arguments and add them. See the symmetry?

Comment: Yes. `&` changes `args` into a list. So whether `args` is a single element or multiple elements or a vector, `args` will become a list. If `apply` is given a list it will unwrap it into its elements. But apply needs an operator/function of some sort as its first argument. In fact `apply` takes two arguments so when it gets more than two it will unwrap only the last argument and try to turn all the preceding arguments into the operator/function that will 'do something' to the newly uncovered elements.

Comment: @ChrisMurphy Exactly. Though `args` is a list of the excess arguments. If there are none then it will be `nil`, If you supply vectors as the extra arguments `args` will be a list of those vectors. Thus the argument types are in tact inside `args` which always is a list. `apply` takes two or more arguments where the first has to be a callable and the last a list of zero or more elements.

Comment: There's no vector being passed in the example, so I didn't really need to bring them up! However if one vector was passed in `&` would convert it into a list where the first element was a vector. And just to cover the edge case you mention of only `f` being passed into `update_contacts!` - then the atom reference would not change at all - nothing would happen.

Comment: @ChrisMurphy `&` doesn't convert anything it just slurps excess arguments.  `(defn my-list [& rest] rest) (my-list [1 2 3] [4 5 6]) ; ==> ([1 2 3] [4 5 6])`. You clearly see the vectors are not changed, they are just put in a list. `apply` does the opposite. `(apply  concat  (my-list [1 2 3] [4 5 6])) ;==> (1 2 3 4 5 6)`

Comment: 'convert' was a poor word choice - I do understand - a better wording would have been *the (same) vector* rather than *a vector* - indicating precisely that a new list is created which wraps the arguments.